# Change case to lower

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lowercase

I am new to python and trying to change the case of many strings to lower case.

Many strings are contained as elements of a list and the list itself is a value for a key(string datatype) of a dictionary.

Here is the dictionary :

```
{
'1000268201_693b08cb0e'  :  ['A child in a pink dress is climbing up a set  of stairs in an entry way .', 'A girl going into a wooden building .', 'A little girl climbing into a wooden playhouse .', 'A little girl climbing the stairs to her playhouse .', 'A little girl in a pink dress going into a wooden cabin .'],
'101654506_8eb26cfb60'   :  ['A brown and white dog is running through the snow .', 'A dog is running in the snow', 'A dog running through snow .', 'a white and brown dog is running through a snow covered field .', 'The white and brown dog is running over the surface of the snow .']
}
```

The code written by me for the above dictionary with key `1000268201_693b08cb0e` and `101654506_8eb26cfb60` and the value as a list of sentences is :

```
for i in mapping:
    for j in range(0,len(mapping[i])):
        mapping[i][j]=mapping[i][j].lower();
```

What can be an efficient and concise way of getting the above job done?

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/g1m5A2

Comment: use ASCII values and +/- to convert between upper/lower case like A=65, a=97 so ASCII for a is A ASCII +32

Comment: @Drako Really?????

Comment: @Drako That sounds wrong on so many levels, not the least of which is that `97-65 != 22`

Comment: @Barmar That means I am right !!

Comment: Yes, your code is fine. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I hope, now, the question is well-defined after the edit !!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably simplify this a little more:

```
my_dict = {'some_key': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'another_key': ['D', 'E', 'F']}

for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key] = [x.lower() for x in my_dict[key]]
```

This saves you having to call `len()`.

Comment: I think, I'm iterating over strings and not characters !!

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you can't change individual characters.

Comment: `len()` is really cheap. You're creating new lists instead of modifying the existing lists.

Comment: That is a good point, is performance an issue here?

Comment: @Barmar So, does  lower() operates on strings or characters ?

Comment: Python doesn't have characters as a separate type. Characters are just strings with one element.